# How Do I Bypass Google Login Step For Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access some services that require a google login. I thought it would be a really neat idea to automate it and have been trying to do so. Whenever I use my script to try and log in, however, I get this message:

*This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.*

How do you go about getting around this? I tried researching it but came up with blanks. Is it possible to be logged in prior to running your script?

Comment: show your code and error, please read  [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Logging in to Google is still possible (by exploiting a bypass).

By default, Google detects and effectively blocks all logins from Selenium webdriver.

The following link comes from the Google OAuth Playground, ensuring the practicality of the link. It most likely won't expire any time soon.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email&access_type=offline&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

You can use that link (ie. `driver.get()`) to log into your Google account.

This bypasses the automation checks allows you to log into Google using Selenium. At least for now.

**UPDATE:** As of January 2021, this no longer works.